# Why the onClick() attribute in XML has a strike through on it? what does that mean?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

When I want to add a onClick attribute to my button, in Android Studio, there is a line called strikethrough(The same we can see in Word/office) on it, What does it mean?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phuNp.png)

Comment: I would guess it's marked as deprecated.

Comment: Hover over it. Android Studio will tell you why.

Answer (score -1):

Probably this method is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and do you know what's the replacement for it?

Comment: it doesn't say that is deprecated. I can't find any info about why it is crossed out in XML layout when you are typing it. After it is typed, there is no warning, no deprecation.